# Select code to be ignored by auto indent in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, coding-style

Can i format code and tell Android Studio not to  reformat it when i run auto indent file?

For example, i might want to structure my code like this:

```
returnFragment = when (questionKind) {

            QuestionKind.TEXT.int        -> GenericTextFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)  //TEXT = 0

            QuestionKind.FREE_TEXT.int   -> GenericTextFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)  //TEXTAREA = 1

            QuestionKind.CHECKBOX.int    -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)       //CHECKBOX = 2

            QuestionKind.RADIO.int       -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)       //RADIO = 3

            QuestionKind.IMAGE.int       -> ImagePickerFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)  //FILE = 4

            QuestionKind.NUMERICAL.int   -> GenericTextFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)  //NUMERICAL = 5

            QuestionKind.MULTISELECT.int -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)       //MULTISELECT = 6

            QuestionKind.SELECT.int      -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)       //SELECT = 7

            else                         -> GenericFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate)      // CUSTOM
}
```

But as soon as I run auto indent (which will be run by lint pre build) the code reverts back to

```
returnFragment = when (questionKind) {

            QuestionKind.TEXT.int -> GenericTextFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //TEXT = 0

            QuestionKind.FREE_TEXT.int -> GenericTextFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //TEXTAREA = 1

            QuestionKind.CHECKBOX.int -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //CHECKBOX = 2

            QuestionKind.RADIO.int -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //RADIO = 3

            QuestionKind.IMAGE.int -> ImagePickerFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //FILE = 4

            QuestionKind.NUMERICAL.int -> GenericTextFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //NUMERICAL = 5

            QuestionKind.MULTISELECT.int -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //MULTISELECT = 6

            QuestionKind.SELECT.int -> SelectFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) //SELECT = 7

            else -> GenericFragment.newInstance(question, pagerDelegate) // CUSTOM
}
```

Whether it's cleaner or not is irrelevant. 
Is there a way to tell the IDE to ignore pre-indented code and only format the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following:

```
 // @formatter:off
...
...
<Code for which you want to turn off formatting>
...
...
// @formatter:on
```

refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style.html section "Formatter Control" for more information.